# Motion of non-homogeneous string fixed at both ends when pulled at a point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, string, vibrations

How to solve displacement and velocity profile of string which has density $d_{1}$ till distance $x$ and density $d_{2}$ from $l - x$ to $x$ fixed at both ends and when given initial displacement and velocity profile like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be broken down into parts.  Since the string is piece-wise homogeneous (finite sections of uniform density), you can solve for each homogeneous part using the usual homogeneous wave equation.  If the entire string were homogeneous, you would then impose the initial and boundary conditions to reduce the general solution to the solution to your problem.  In this case, you do the same thing, but each portion has a "boundary condition" that simply states that the portions are part of the same string.  The interface condition is that, at the interface position $x'$, the displacement is continuous (the string is not broken at the interface) and the displacement gradient is continuous (related to the fact that the string does not have infinite acceleration).  Mathematically these conditions may be written as $y_1(x')=y_2(x')$, assuming that $y$ is the transverse displacement and that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the general displacement solutions for the two string segments, and $\partial_xy_1(x')=\partial_xy_2(x')$.  These interface conditions stitch the two solutions together, and then the initial conditions may be applied as before.

Good luck!